# AFHTTPRequestOperationManager doesn't send custom HTTP header

Tags: objective-c, xcode, http-headers, afnetworking, afhttprequestoperation

I want to use `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` in my project. Each request should contain an authorization header. Otherwise server reports an error.

Well, I create an `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`:

```
- (void) setManager:(AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *)manager
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
        _manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"text/plain", nil];
        _manager.operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
        [_manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"XsziXjva92jAO29jng0wpBmKFJ92s9q" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    });
}
```

And send a request with the help of the manager:

```
+ (void) requestBoards
{
    // show me my manager headers
    DLog(@"%@", [[[[RequestManager instance] manager] requestSerializer] HTTPRequestHeaders]);
    [[[RequestManager instance] manager] GET:URL_BOARDS parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        DLog(@"good");
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        // show me request headers
        DLog(@"%@", operation.request.allHTTPHeaderFields);
    }];
}
```

Each `DLog` shows:

```
[RequestManager requestBoards]_block_invoke_2 [Line 66] {
    "Accept-Language" = "en;q=1";
    Authorization = XsziXjva92jAO29jng0wpBmKFJ92s9q;
    "User-Agent" = "SITE/1.0 (iPhone Simulator; iOS 8.1; Scale/2.00)";
}
```

And the server response is no good:

```
{"data": {}, "error_text": "Key None is unauthorized, sorry :/", "success": false, "error": "unauthorized_key"}
```

I decided to check my request with Wireshark and there is no **Authorization** header at all. What am I doing wrong?

Added:

Only **Authorization** header isn't send by `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`. I have changed header title to **AuthorizationLOL** and is was sent successfully